# How to install Samsung Unified Linux Driver in Fedora 23?

Tags: fedora

I am getting errors when I am trying to install the samsung linux drivers in my Fedora 23 installation. I uncompressed the file uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz and tried to run the install.sh file to install printing/scanning utilities.

```
$sudo sh install.sh
./noarch/scripting_utils: line 144: cd: ./noarch/..: Not a directory
INTERNAL ERROR: ABORT: ''DIST_DIR' is undefined', execution aborted
call stack:
[1]=./noarch/bash_debugging:34:_abort_execution
[2]=./noarch/package_utils:81:nls_init
[3]=./noarch/package_utils:248:environment_init
[4]=install.sh:11:main
```

Has anyone else confronted this? Are they not compatible with Fedora OS?

PS) I downloaded the driver from here http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/SL-C460FW/SEE

Comment: Does the scanner function work with this driver? If it does and you still have the original file, do you mind uploading it somewhere and sharing a link, as by now Samsung has all but eliminated the Linux driver for this model and all 3d party hosters/projects have all gone down too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed just fine right now on Fedora 23 (just to test, I don't have a compatible machine).

After extracting everything from the file `uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz`, you should have a new folder called `uld`. Make sure you `cd` into that before trying to run `install.sh`. The first line of the output that you're seeing suggests that you're not in that directory, because there's a folder called `noarch` in there, that's not being seen by the script. Note that it's a relative directory, so they both need to be in the same directory, and it may expect that you execute from within that directory.

Here's what I see in that directory:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 grdryn grdryn 4.0K Oct 26 03:00 i386
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 grdryn grdryn  446 Apr 24  2015 install-printer.sh
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 grdryn grdryn  446 Apr 24  2015 install-scanner.sh
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 grdryn grdryn  848 Apr 24  2015 install.sh
drwxrwxrwx. 5 grdryn grdryn 4.0K Oct 26 03:00 noarch
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 grdryn grdryn  328 Apr 24  2015 uninstall-printer.sh
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 grdryn grdryn  328 Apr 24  2015 uninstall-scanner.sh
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 grdryn grdryn  383 Apr 24  2015 uninstall.sh
drwxrwxrwx. 2 grdryn grdryn 4.0K Oct 26 03:00 x86_64
```

Comment: I tried it in a virtual box just a while ago and the installation proceeded. 

In the physical machine where I have this problem (I can't test it again right now) my home directory is mounted (network profile) and my user account is also sudoer so I can install and test stuff.

Do you think my mounted /home is related with my installation issues ? I usually install software and update without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it.

I was trying to install it from my "Downloads" directory. I moved the tar.gz file to /tmp/, decompressed it there and then executed again `$sudo sh install.sh` in my uld directory.

I am not sure why it didn't work in my "Downloads" directory.